# elasticsearch - scout:import doesn't import second model

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I am trying to import items and tags but it always imports the first one and ignores the second one (doesn't matter which one: if I import an item it will not import a tag and vice versa)

```
mappings: {
    items: {
        properties: {}
    }
}
```

or

```
mappings: {
    tags: {
        properties: {}
    }
}
```

In both models I am using Searchable and toSearchableArray function...

I am using scout and tamayo/laravel-scout-elastic latest version

so mapping doesn't work for the second model

*Update*

when i trying to put mapping via postman

```
{
"error": {
    "root_cause": [
        {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Rejecting mapping update to [music] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [items, tags]"
        }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "Rejecting mapping update to [music] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [items, tags]"
},
"status": 400
 }
```